# When i install flask via conda, it throws ERROR [PermissionError 13, Permission Denied]?

Tags: flask, anaconda, flask-sqlalchemy, conda, flask-restful

if i try to install flask via conda using

```
conda install -c anaconda flask
```

it shows that some packages would be installed but later i throws error stating

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::conda-4.5.4-py36_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')".
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this means you need to install it as an administrator. [Check out this issue on github for specific instructions.](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7404)

Comment: yeah i did conda install flask and it worked